# Website is not responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm at the moment building a simple website with a header, a vertical nav and a content box and I'm failing in some minor thing. After building the html structure

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="nav_content_container">
                <div class="nav"></div>
                <div class="content"></div>
                <div class="floatkiller"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and giving it some css

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 77%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.header {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.nav_content_container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: azure;
}

.nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.floatkiller {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

my website is failing in beeing responsiv or to be accurate, my site get's a height more than 100% and my `content` box drops out of the `nav_content_container`. If I'm not giving any borders, everything is alright, but after applying the borders my website is broken. Why is the border making everything broken?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1">` into your `<head>` tag. You also need to use `@media query` so that an element changes on a specific resolution, like this:

```
@media screen (max-width: 1366px)
 { 
   /* element that changes on specific screen resouliton*/
   /* h1 { color: red; } AS AN EXAMPLE */
 }
```

But, if you are using Bootstrap, then the only thing you need to do, is to add classes like `col-lg-x` , `col-md-x` `col-xs-x` ("x" is a number from 1 - 12), and those classes do the job for you.

Read about them here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score -1):

Because you are giving border in `px`. Change them to `%`. It will get fixed.